# How can I filter a Django queryset by the latest of a related model?

Tags: django, django-models

Imagine I have the following 2 models in a contrived example:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Login(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='logins')
    success = models.BooleanField()
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = 'datetime'
```

How can I get a queryset of Users, which only contains users whose last login was not successful.

I know the following does not work, but it illustrates what I want to get:

```
User.objects.filter(login__latest__success=False)
```

I'm guessing I can do it with Q objects, and/or Case When, and/or some other form of annotation and filtering, but I can't suss it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a `Subquery` here:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

latest_login = Subquery(Login.objects.filter(
    user=OuterRef('pk')
).order_by('-datetime').values('success')[:1])

User.objects.annotate(
    latest_login=latest_login
).filter(latest_login=False)
```

This will generate a query that looks like:

```
SELECT auth_user.*, (
    SELECT U0.success
    FROM login U0
    WHERE U0.user_id = auth_user.id
    ORDER BY U0.datetime DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS latest_login
FROM auth_user
WHERE (
    SELECT U0.success
    FROM login U0
    WHERE U0.user_id = auth_user.id
    ORDER BY U0.datetime
    DESC LIMIT 1
  ) = False
```

So the outcome of the `Subquery` is the `success` of the latest `Login` object, and if that is `False`, we add the related `User` to the `QuerySet`.

Answer (score 0):

You can first annotate the max dates, and then filter based on success and the max date using [F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F):

```
User.objects.annotate(max_date=Max('logins__datetime'))\
    .filter(logins__datetime=F('max_date'), logins__success=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

for check bool use `success=False` and for get latest use `latest()`
your filter has been look this:

```
User.objects.filter(success=False).latest()
```

Comment: There are some problems here: (1) a `User` has no `success` field here, and (2) this would give you the "latest" (well there is not really a latest) `User` that has had an unsuccessful login.